# Sqlite remove duplicates within specific time range

Tags: sqlite

I know there are many questions asked about removing duplicates in SQL. However in my case it is slightly more complicated.

These are data with Barcode which repeats over a month. Therefore it is expected that there will be entries with the same Barcode. However it is found out that due to possibly a machine bug, same data will be recorded within 4-5 minutes timeframe 2 to 3 times. It does not happen for every entry, but it happens rather frequently.

Allow me to demonstrate with a sample table which contains the same Barcode "A00000"

```
Barcode No      Date                A    B   C       D
A00000  1499456 10/10/2019 3:28     607 94  1743    72D
A00000  1803564 10/20/2019 22:09    589 75  1677    14D
A00000  1803666 10/20/2019 22:13    589 75  1677    14D
A00000  1803751 10/20/2019 22:17    589 75  1677    14D
A00000  2084561 10/30/2019 12:22    583 86  1677    14D
A00000  2383742 11/9/2019 23:18     594 81  1650    07D
```

As you can see the entries on 10/20 contains identical data which are duplicates which should be removed so only one of the entry remains (any of the entry is fine and the exact time is not the main concern). The "No" column is a pure arbitrary number which can be safely disregarded. The other entries should be remain as it is.

I know this should be done by using "Group by", but I am struggling on how to write the conditions. I have tried also using table INNER JOIN itself and then remove these selected results:

```
     T2.A = T2.B AND  
     T2.[Date] > T1.[Date] AND
     strftime('%s',T2.[Date]) - strftime('%s',T1.[Date]) < 600
```

The results still seem a bit off as some of the entries are selected twice and some are not selected. I am still not used to SQL style of thinking. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should store your datetime values in an ISO format, something like `'2019-01-01 12:34:56'`.  In the current format, it will be hard to aggregate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the `Date` column complicates things a bit, but otherwise the solution basically is to use `GROUP BY` in the normal way. In the following, I've assumed the name of the table is `test`:

```
WITH sane as
   (SELECT *, 
           substr(date,1,instr(date, ' ') - 1) as time 
    FROM test)
SELECT Barcode, max(No), Date, A, B, C, D
FROM sane
GROUP BY barcode, time;
```

The use of max() is perhaps unneeded but it gives some determinacy, which might be helpful.